# Is passive cooling sufficient for an nVidia Tesla K20?

Tags: graphics-card, cooling

I'm looking into buying an Nvidia Tesla K20 to do some machine learning computer tasks as well as some rendering on my desktop. The one I'm looking at specifically is passive cooled however. Is that really sufficient for this card? There might be occasions where the GPU will be running at full load for days. Should I be worried about the passive cooling or can it handle it?

Comment: The card in question was engineered to be passively cooled.

Comment: If the card doesn't come with active cooling then it doesn't *need* active cooling. Chances are that the card is pitifully low powered though. It might be enough depending on your task, but be aware that passive cooling implies low power and therefore low perfomance.

Comment: So theoretically I shouldn't have any issues running that card at full load in my desktop PC? Someone else told me previously that it's meant for servers or something like that.

Comment: Chances are though that the K20 is not passively cooled, given that it has a TDP of 225 watts: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Tesla

Comment: That's what confuses me because a lot of them on ebay and elsewhere list them as passively cooled (and pulled from servers). The pictures of the cards also don't show any evidence of fans inside either. So I wasn't sure if this is some incredible passive cooling or something else.

Comment: Okay, so it *is* passively cooled (https://www.anandtech.com/show/6446/nvidia-launches-tesla-k20-k20x-gk110-arrives-at-last) but at 225 watts you'd definitely need good airflow. So yes, it is designed to be used in an actively cooled server.

Comment: From http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-3517141/tesla-k20-compatibility-dell-precision-690.html : "Passively cooled Tesla cards are only suitable for specific server chassis that have been designed to provide sufficient airflow. Not a power supply thing, but an airflow thing. Desktop chassis are not designed to flow enough air over the card. "

Comment: "Someone else told me previously that it's meant for servers or something like that." - It likely is designed for servers.  If you don't have a server look for a different product.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, no wonder it was so cheap compared to the actively cooled models. I'm guessing if I did try and use this card in a desktop PC anyways, it'd probably burn out pretty quickly then.

Answer (score 0):

While there are versions of the K20 that are passively cooled they are intended to be used in an environment where good airflow is guaranteed. This puts it firmly in a 1U server environment where there are several fans on the front of the chassis pulling in cool air and pushing it out the enclosure via the K20.

Without active air movement in the chassis at 225 watts the K20 will quickly hit a thermal limit and either shut down or simply die. There is only so much heat that can be dissipated via passive cooling and, from experience and testing, even far less at 100W requires some pretty hefty heatsinking and at least *some* airflow to keep the temperature below that which will cause semiconductors switch to being light and/or smoke emitting diodes.

A desktop chassis is not designed to focus the airflow out via specific components such at the K20 while the limits of server designs (at 1U tall) makes it quite easy to focus airflow out via a heatsink assembly such as would be on the K20.

You could probably make a custom fan assembly for it, though it might just be easier to buy an active cooled version.

You should note that there are several active cooled desktop graphics cards at the 225W power range and even they get up to 80+ degrees celcius under load. Without a fan they would not survive particularly long.